# Is there a way to correlate n arrays?

Tags: python, numpy, correlation

I need to correlate n arrays that I have combined into a list which looks like:

```py
array_corr = [array([a1]), array([a2]), array([a3]), .... array([an])]

corr_mat = np.corrcoef([array_corr])
```

But I am getting the error:

> operands could not be broadcast together.

All arrays are the same size. I don't understand the source of error.

I expect the output to be an nxn matrix since there are n arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make `array_corr` a pure numpy 2d-array and send it to `np.corrcoef` without brackets (you are creating a list with only one matrix element this way):

```
array_corr = np.array([
    [1,2,3,4,5],
    [1,6,3,3,5],
    [1,2,9,4,3],
    [2,1,3,8,5],
    [6,6,2,6,5],
])

corr_mat = np.corrcoef(array_corr)

corr_mat
```

returns:

```
array([[ 1.        ,  0.40555355,  0.30460385,  0.74074375, -0.18257419],
       [ 0.40555355,  1.        , -0.05764881, -0.11092108,  0.07404361],
       [ 0.30460385, -0.05764881,  1.        ,  0.16777868, -0.92688   ],
       [ 0.74074375, -0.11092108,  0.16777868,  1.        ,  0.1040313 ],
       [-0.18257419,  0.07404361, -0.92688   ,  0.1040313 ,  1.        ]])
```

Comment: I am importing data from the web through a for loop which is why I have the extra brackets. This is what I'm doing to create array_corr:

    array_corr = []
    for i in range(len(b)):
        df = ek.get_timeseries(b[0][i], start_date = '2016-01-01', end_date = '2019-01-01'
        array_corr = array_corr +[ np.array(df['CLOSE'])]'

I am not sure how to make a pure 2d array in this situation.

Comment: Add `super_array = np.array(array_corr)` and use `np.corrcoef(super_array)`

Comment: That did not help. The format of the super_array is the same as that of array_coeff.

Comment: Then try to use just: `corr_mat = np.corrcoef(array_corr)` (without brackets).